# Having problem on mapping JSON data in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

we are building an e-commerce website using React and Redux as a front-end. And we need to display categories data on the category page. We successfully get JSON data in console, but we have a problem to display in the category component page.

Please help to solve this problem

**reducer/categories.js:**

```
import { RECEIVE_CATEGORIES } from "../constants/ActionTypes";

const initialState = {
  categories: []
};

const categoryReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_CATEGORIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        categories: action.categories
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default categoryReducer;
```

**action/index.js:**

```
import shop from '../api/shop'
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes'
import store from "../store";
import { toast  } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';

export const fetchProductsBegin = () => ({
    type: types.FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN
});

export const fetchCategoryBegin = () => ({
    type: types.FETCH_CATEGORIES_BEGIN
});


export const receiveProducts = products => ({
    type: types.RECEIVE_PRODUCTS,
    products
})

export const receiveCategories = categories => ({
    type: types.RECEIVE_CATEGORIES,
    categories
})

export const getAllProducts = () => dispatch => { 
    dispatch(fetchProductsBegin()); 
    return shop.getProducts(
        products => {
        products.then((data)=> { dispatch(receiveProducts(data));})})

}

export const getAllCategories = () => dispatch => { 
    dispatch(fetchCategoryBegin()); 
    return shop.getCategories(
        products => {
        products.then((data)=> { 
            console.log("executed");
            dispatch(receiveCategories(data));})})

}
export const fetchSingleProduct = productId => ({
    type: types.FETCH_SINGLE_PRODUCT,
    productId
})




//it seems that I should probably use this as the basis for "Cart"
export const addToCart = (product,qty) => (dispatch) => {
    toast.success("Item Added to Cart");
        dispatch(addToCartUnsafe(product, qty))

}
export const addToCartAndRemoveWishlist = (product,qty) => (dispatch) => {
    toast.success("Item Added to Cart");
    dispatch(addToCartUnsafe(product, qty));
    dispatch(removeFromWishlist(product));
}
export const addToCartUnsafe = (product, qty) => ({
    type: types.ADD_TO_CART,
    product,
    qty
});
export const removeFromCart = product_id => (dispatch) => {
    toast.error("Item Removed from Cart");
    dispatch({
        type: types.REMOVE_FROM_CART,
        product_id
    })
};
export const incrementQty = (product,qty) => (dispatch) => {
    toast.success("Item Added to Cart");
    dispatch(addToCartUnsafe(product, qty))

}
export const decrementQty = productId => (dispatch) => {
    toast.warn("Item Decrement Qty to Cart");

    dispatch({
    type: types.DECREMENT_QTY,
    productId})
};



//it seems that I should probably use this as the basis for "Wishlist"
export const addToWishlist = (product) => (dispatch) => {
    toast.success("Item Added to Wishlist");
    dispatch(addToWishlistUnsafe(product))

}
export const addToWishlistUnsafe = (product) => ({
    type: types.ADD_TO_WISHLIST,
    product
});
export const removeFromWishlist = product_id => (dispatch) => {
    toast.error("Item Removed from Wishlist");
    dispatch({
        type: types.REMOVE_FROM_WISHLIST,
        product_id
    })
};


//Compare Products
export const addToCompare = (product) => (dispatch) => {
    toast.success("Item Added to Compare");
    dispatch(addToCompareUnsafe(product))

}
export const addToCompareUnsafe= (product) => ({
    type: types.ADD_TO_COMPARE,
    product
});
export const removeFromCompare = product_id => ({
    type: types.REMOVE_FROM_COMPARE,
    product_id
});


// Filters
export const filterBrand = (brand) => ({
    type: types.FILTER_BRAND,
    brand
});
export const filterColor = (color) => ({
    type: types.FILTER_COLOR,
    color
});
export const filterPrice = (value) => ({
    type: types.FILTER_PRICE,
    value
});
export const filterSort = (sort_by) => ({
    type: types.SORT_BY,
    sort_by
});


// Currency
export const changeCurrency = (symbol) => ({
    type: types.CHANGE_CURRENCY,
    symbol
});
```

**Api/shop.js:**

```
/**
 * Mocking client-server processing
 */
import axios from "axios";
// import _products from './data.json'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import store from "../store";
import { receiveProducts } from "../actions/index";

const TIMEOUT = 100;

const _products = axios
  .get(`http://localhost:4000/product`)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });

const _category = axios
  .get(`http://localhost:4000/categories`)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  });

export default {
  getProducts: (cb, timeout) =>
    setTimeout(() => cb(_products), timeout || TIMEOUT),
  getCategories: (cb, timeout) =>
    setTimeout(() => cb(_category), timeout || TIMEOUT),
  buyProducts: (payload, cb, timeout) =>
    setTimeout(() => cb(), timeout || TIMEOUT),
};
```

**element-category.jsx:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

import Breadcrumb from "../../common/breadcrumb";
import { Slider6, Slider4 } from "../../../services/script";
import "react-tabs/style/react-tabs.scss";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getAllCategories } from "../../../actions";

class ElementCategory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categories: this.props.categories
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllCategories();
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.categories);
    return (
      <div>
        <Breadcrumb parent={"Elements"} title={"Category"} />

        {/*Category One*/}
        <div className="container">
          <section className="section-b-space">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <Slider {...Slider6} className="slide-6 no-arrow">
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat1.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>shoes</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat2.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>casual shoes</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat3.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>formal shoes</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat4.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>flat</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat5.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>heels</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat6.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>boots</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat2.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>casual shoes</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-block">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div className="category-image">
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/icon/cat3.png`}
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                    </a>
                    <div className="category-details">
                      <a href="#">
                        <h5>casual shoes</h5>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Slider>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>

        {/*Category Two*/}
        <section className="p-0 ratio2_1">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row category-border">
              <div className="col-sm-4 border-padding">
                <div className="category-banner">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat1.png`}
                      className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-box">
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>men</h2>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 border-padding">
                <div className="category-banner">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat2.png`}
                      className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-box">
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>women</h2>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 border-padding">
                <div className="category-banner">
                  <div>
                    <img
                      src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat3.png`}
                      className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-box">
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>kids</h2>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        {/*Category Three*/}
        <div className="container category-button">
          <section className="section-b-space">
            <div className="row partition1">
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  airbag
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  burn bag
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  briefcase
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  carpet bag
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  money bag
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline btn-block">
                  tucker bag
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>

        {/*Category Four*/}
        <div className="category-bg ratio_square">
          <div className="container-fluid p-0">
            <div className="row order-section">
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <a href="#" className="image-block">
                  <img
                    alt=""
                    src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat1.jpg`}
                    className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <div className="contain-block even">
                  <div>
                    <h6>new products</h6>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>zipper storage bag</h2>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-solid category-btn">
                      -80% off
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h6>
                        <span>shop now</span>
                      </h6>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <a href="#" className="image-block">
                  <img
                    alt=""
                    src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat2.jpg`}
                    className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <div className="contain-block">
                  <div>
                    <h6>on sale</h6>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>tucker bag</h2>
                    </a>{" "}
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-solid category-btn">
                      save 30% off
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h6>
                        <span>shop now</span>
                      </h6>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <a href="#" className="image-block even">
                  <img
                    alt=""
                    src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/cat3.jpg`}
                    className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                  />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-sm-4 p-0">
                <div className="contain-block">
                  <div>
                    <h6>summer sale</h6>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h2>gate check bag</h2>
                    </a>{" "}
                    <a href="#" className="btn btn-solid category-btn">
                      minimum 50% off
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                      <h6>
                        <span>shop now</span>
                      </h6>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/*Category Five*/}
        <section className="ratio_portrait">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <Slider {...Slider4} className="slide-4 category-m no-arrow">
                  <div>
                    <div className="category-wrapper">
                      <div>
                        <div>
                          <img
                            src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/watch/cat1.png`}
                            className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                            alt=""
                          />
                        </div>
                        <h4>watch models</h4>
                        <ul className="category-link">
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">d1 milano</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">damaskeening</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">diving watch</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">dollar watch</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline">
                          view more
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <div className="category-wrapper">
                      <div>
                        <div>
                          <img
                            src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/watch/cat2.png`}
                            className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                            alt=""
                          />
                        </div>
                        <h4>calculator watch</h4>
                        <ul className="category-link">
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Shock-resistant watch</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Skeleton watch</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Slow watch</a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <a href="#">Solar-powered watch</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline">
                          view more
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-wrapper">
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/watch/cat3.png`}
                          className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                      <h4>Antimagnetic watch</h4>
                      <ul className="category-link">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Watchmaking conglomerates</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Breitling SA</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Casio watches</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Citizen Watch</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline">
                        view more
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-wrapper">
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/watch/cat2.png`}
                          className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                      <h4>History of watches</h4>
                      <ul className="category-link">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Manufacture d'horlogerie</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Mechanical watch</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">Microbrand watches</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">MIL-W-46374</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline">
                        view more
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="category-wrapper">
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/watch/cat1.png`}
                          className="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img"
                          alt=""
                        />
                      </div>
                      <h4>watch models</h4>
                      <ul className="category-link">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">d1 milano</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">damaskeening</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">diving watch</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#">dollar watch</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <a href="#" className="btn btn-outline">
                        view more
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Slider>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        {/*Category Six*/}
        <section className="section-b-space">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row background">
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="contain-bg">
                    <h4 data-hover="size 06">size 06</h4>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="contain-bg">
                    <h4>size 07</h4>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="contain-bg">
                    <h4>size 08</h4>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="contain-bg">
                    <h4>size 09</h4>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <a href="#">
                  <div className="contain-bg">
                    <h4>size 10</h4>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return {
    categories: store.category.categories
  };
};

// export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllCategories })(ElementCategory);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllCategories })(ElementCategory);
```

Comment: What do you mean in the console? Are you talking about the Redux dev tools store or do you mean you get the expected JSON where you console.log it in the render function of the component? Are you combining your reducers?

Comment: Does it show error or sth?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01, no error in console.log, but i don't know have to display in react component.please help me